# Error starting wso2 IS server version 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have downloaded the WSO2 IS 5.0.0 , when I started running the server .

I am getting the following error, not sure where it is picking the wrong password from :

```
[2015-12-16 12:46:46,541]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.observers.APIStatusObserverList} -  Attempt to reinitialize APIStatusObserverList - Skipping
[2015-12-16 12:46:48,709] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO} -  Failed to retrieve the API Context 
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [8004-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:133)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:277)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:133)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:241)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.createSession(SessionRemote.java:219)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:111)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:95)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
```

Additional Info:
I am using the following documentation to configure IS as the keyManager.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.1

What I found is only if I change the username and password of the newly added datasources to default username and password , then the server is starting.

Comment: Have you done any config changes? I

Comment: And also are you is it pure IS 5.0.0? Because AFAIK org.wso2.carbon.apimgt is not in the default IS500 pack

Comment: I have downloaded the IS with the service pack. Actually I am trying to configure IS as the key Manager for WS02 API manager.

Comment: Added additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created the setup using Pre-Packaged IS 5.0.0 with API Manager 1.9.1 and API Manager 1.9.1 as describe in `[1]`.  while starting the server there is no error get printed on the console. The main reason behind the error is that you are changing the wso2carbondb credential shipped with the the IS.

```
[1]: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.1
```